# Replicating vector elements by index

Tags: r, vector, replication

I have an integer vector:
    `a <- c(1,1,3,1,4)`
where each element in a indicates how many times its index should be replicated in a new vector.

So the resulting vector should be:
    `b <- c(1,2,3,3,3,4,5,5,5,5)`

What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example using `rep`:

```
rep(seq_along(a),a)
1 2 3 3 3 4 5 5 5 5
```

Another less efficient option is to use `inverse.rle` :

```
inverse.rle(list(lengths=a,values=seq_along(a)))
[1] 1 2 3 3 3 4 5 5 5 5
```